# ALL uses of <> in SSMS schemata - Found one that I can't identify from any search

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, ssms, ssms-2014

Preface: Sort of green to this, apologies if it is beyond obvious.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014, and in one of our schemata found this:

[image]

I've gone down a number of rabbit holes regarding variants in schemata, != functionality, schema objects, and can't seem to get a handle on what this syntax definitively stands for or accomplishes.

Help appreciated.

Comment: It's considered rude here to post an image instead of the actual code.

Comment: I am unable to do that since this code snippet (from my work, where we deal with PII) occurs in a virtual machine that does not allow anything to be copied out. (Rudeness unintended.)

Comment: So you retype it. That's what we'll have to do. It's much more efficient for you to retype it once than for us to each retype it individually as we try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [SSMS template parameters](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/i-thought-everyone-did-it-like-that-ssms-templates/). The syntax includes name, datatype, and example value (blank in your case).

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to bring up a dialogue box to fill them in.

Or if that doesn't do anything see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/monicarivera/2012/08/26/enabling-the-ctrl-shift-m-keyboard-shortcut-for-template-parameters-in-ssms-2012/) article for how to fix.

Comment: Very interesting -- and I never would have known to google template parameters, which explains why my searches were unproductive. Really appreciate insight into this mystery!

Answer (score 0):

It's autogenerated code - in this case for INSERT INTO query. Those values in <> should be replaced with proper values - they're just hints including column name and type.